# How do I test changes to a requestAnimationFrame shim on OSX Mavericks?

Tags: javascript, html, macos, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

Suppose I'm starting with the [requestAnimationFrame shim by Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/):

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
  return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
          window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
          window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
          function( callback ){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
          };
})();
```

and I'm running on OS X Mavericks, and I want to make changes to the shim - for example:

```
var myfunc = function() {
    if (typeof(window.requestAnimationFrame) != "undefined") {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame;
    } else if (typeof(window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame) != "undefined") {
        return window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame;
    } else if (typeof(window.mozRequestAnimationFrame) != "undefined") {
        return window.mozRequestAnimationFrame;
    } else {
        return function(callback) {
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
    }
};
window.requestAnimFrame = myfunc;
```

Now to test this shim and make sure it works on Mavericks - I need a browser that this shim applies to. By default my browsers are Chrome 31 and Firefox 24. ([For which this shim is redundant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177323/for-which-browsers-are-we-using-paul-irishs-requestanimationframe-shim))

My question is **how do I test changes to a requestAnimationFrame shim on OSX Mavericks?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To *test* you can clear the native one:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame = undefined;
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame = undefined;
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame = undefined;

... run shim here...
```

BTW You also need to make your shim self-invoking:

```
var myfunc = (function() { ... })();
```

See **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/HHxj9/)**.